# Flask AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'

Tags: python, flask, openssl

When i run my flask micro-service, I get  Error which look like this: 
"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'"

This error became when I install pyopenssl

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main_page():
    return render_template('sign.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000 ,host="localhost", ssl_context='', debug=True)
```